# Get the color of a pixel by its xyz coordinates

Tags: three.js, webgl

I need to get the color of an image texture on a mesh at a given xyz point (mouse click + ray cast). How can I achieve it in THREE.js?

I know I could use gl.readPixels from plain webgl, but it's not a valid option for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to read the color for collision-testing? There is no backbuffer like there was for openGL. I could help you out with collision testing, but not for reading a color from a pixel of a texture.

Comment: Test ray intersection with all triangles in the scene and you'll get your intersection point. Then you could retrieve the barycentric coordinates from that triangle and use those to find interpolated UVs for your intersected point. Once you have UVs, sample the texture with `gl.readPixels`. Does that suit you?

Comment: The use case is simple: get the color where the user clicked. The user will have to click on a mesh with a image as texture (a world globe). And since there is other stuff on the scene (flight paths) gl.readPixels would bring inacurate results if you click on a path rather than an actual country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended using a separate canvas, in which I load the image texture, translate the three.js coordinates into canvas one and read the pixel. Something like this:

```
// point is a THREE.Vector3
var getColor = function(point, callback) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'assets/img/myImage.png';
  img.onload = function() {
    // get the xy coords from the point
    var xyCoords = convertVector3ToXY(point);
    // create a canvas to manipulate the image
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    // get the pixel data and callback
    var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    callback(pixelData);
  }
};
```

Thanks